# How to create salesman in Odoo10

Tags: python, xml, configuration, odoo, odoo-10

I am new to Odoo and i am using Odoo v10.
The client asked me to create a Salesperson / Salesman so the system should look like 
**suppliers->Inventory->salesman->customers**

I want the salesman to take products from inventory  and but them in his account , and he is the one how can sell them to customers and clients, and i can create many of accounts for the salesman .

Any Idea please ? can i find any plugin to help me ,Thanks in advance .

Comment: You really need to read the docs before asking a question@Ghada Rahhal

Comment: Naveen , i readed it , but not the same as am looking for , 
salesparson still can view all inventory on the system ,  i want him to view only his own products , 

what is the best way to do that ?

Comment: see my answer@GhandaRahhal

Answer (score 0):

Ho through the documentation below, same concept for 10 too

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/9.0/crm/salesteam/manage/create_salesperson.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but is the when i login as salesperson , salesperson can view all inventory in the system , and i dont know how to transfer products to his account ?

Answer (score 0):

In record rules of your security file:

```
    <record id="any_id_own_salesperson" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Sales Persons</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_inventory_modelname" />
        <field name="global" eval="False" />
        <field name="domain_force">['|',('user_id','=',user.id),('user_id','=',False)]
        </field>
        <field name="groups"
            eval="[(4, ref('sales_team.group_sale_salesman'))]" />
    </record>
```